# Finding polar representation of $\dot{x} = -y+x(1-x^{2}-y^{2}), \dot{y} = x+y(1-x^{2}-y^{2}). $

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, vector-fields

We have the system

$$\dot{x} = -y+x(1-x^{2}-y^{2})\\
\dot{y} = x+y(1-x^{2}-y^{2}).
$$

Now this ends up as 
$$ \dot{r} = r(1-r^{2})\\
\dot{\theta} = 1
$$
in polar coordinates, but I do not see how.

I reckon we should use the standard transformation $x= r\cos{\theta}$ and $y = r \sin{\theta}$ but how one derive the latter representation? I see how $-x^{2}-y^{2} = - ( x^{2} + y^{2} ) = -r^{2}(\sin^{2}{\theta}+\cos^{2}{\theta}) = -r^{2}$, but that is just a small part of it I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
r\dot r=x\dot x+y\dot y=r^2(1-r^2)
$$
and for the angle
$$
r^2\dot θ=x\dot y-y\dot x=r^2
$$
Now cancel the $r$'s on the left side ...

Comment: Thank you. And those equations are just standard? I have not seen them being introduced in the book I am working from (dynamical systems and differential equations)

Comment: Yes, they are quite standard and easy to confirm for $(x,y)=(r\cosθ,r\sinθ)$.