# Having problems with drawing of a phase portrait of system of ODES in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I'm stuck with a problem which bothers me.

It's about the following differential equation system:

$$
x^{\prime}=y-(x^2+y^2-1)\cdot x\\
y^{\prime}=-x-(x^2+y^2-1)\cdot y
$$

I have transformed the system in polar coordinates, which looks like:
$$
r^\prime=-r\cdot(r^2-1)\\
\theta^\prime=-1
$$

Now to the part where I am desperate and don't know what to do:

First of all, I want to know how to determine the equilibrium points of the system in polar coordinates, since $\theta=-1$. How does that effect the equilibrium points. (0,0) is a equlibrium of the system in normal coordinates but is it also one of the system in polar coordinates?

And my bigger problem is the drawing of the phase portrait of the system in polar coordinates. I don't know how to draw it without any use of computer help, because I have to do it on my own in the exam.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: How did you get $\theta = 1$? Shouldn't there be a derivative of $\theta$ somewhere?

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I meant the derivative of $\theta$ of course

Comment: No worries. At this point, I suggest you actually _solve_ the system of ODEs in polar coordinates and see what happens. Then to answer your first question, try to determine the value(s) of $r$ and $\theta$ that would make $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = (0, 0)$. Finally, to answer your 'bigger problem', I think you should look at the radial ODE and think about what the sign of $r'$ is when $r < 1, r = 1$ and when $r > 1$.

Comment: Very similar : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3663369

Comment: @JeanMarie The question you linked is a very similar system, but the OP here is asking something completely different to what was asked in that question.

Comment: @Mattos: You are right

Comment: @mattos Thank you mattos, now I see that $(r,\theta)=(0,0)$ is the only equilibrium of the system. I have solved the ode in polar coordinates and  I just figured out that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}r=1$. Does that mean that I have a circle with radius 1 which is a limit cycle? How do I draw the trajectories in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The important, *qualitative* understanding of your differential system is that it can be expressed as:

$$\begin{cases}x'&=& \ \ \ y-ax,\\
y'&=&-x-ay \end{cases} \ \text{with} \ a=a(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$$

i.e, along level curves:

$$a=k,\  \ k \ \text{constant}$$

which are circles with radii $\sqrt{a+1}$, the behavior of your "arrows" will be that of the *linear* system:

$$\binom{x'}{y'}=\begin{pmatrix}-a & 1\\-1&-a\end{pmatrix} \binom{x}{y}$$

which is a similitude matrix (with a distinction between the cases

$$a<0 \ vs. \ a>0 \ \iff \ (x,y) \ \text{ inside/outside unit circle}$$

In this way, in an exam, you can draw a thorough sketch of the phase portrait.

[image]

*Fig. 1: The large view picture on the left is misleading. If you zoom on it (right picture), you will see that a spiraling effect takes place in the vicinity of the origin.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why are the radii $\sqrt{a^2+1}$ and not $\sqrt{a^2-1}$ ? What is a similitude matrix? Can you please explain me step by step how to draw phase portrait of a linear system or provide with a good source?

Comment: Sorry, none of us is right: I made an error $x^2+y^2-1=a \iff x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{1+a})^2$ therefore the radius is $\sqrt{1+a}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. I would give an upvote for your answer, but since I'm new here I can't.

Comment: I think that even if you are new on the site, you can click on the up triangle but it doesn't matter really...

Comment: I can upvote though (+1).